# Symfony form renderer - custom bootstrap checkbox and radio buttons

Tags: symfony, twig, bootstrap-4

I discovered that you can tell symfony to generate forms in bootstrap way, by adding this in your twig.yaml file

```
twig:
   form_themes: ['bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig']
```

this renders renders checkbox in normal bootstrap way like this:

```
<fieldset class="form-group">
   <legend class="col-form-label required">Subjects</legend>
   <div id="form_subjects">
      <div class="form-check">
         <input type="checkbox" id="form_subjects_0" name="form[subjects][]" class="form-check-input" value="1">
         <label class="form-check-label" for="form_subjects_0">4IZ110</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
         <input type="checkbox" id="form_subjects_1" name="form[subjects][]" class="form-check-input" value="2">
         <label class="form-check-label" for="form_subjects_1">4MA106</label>
      </div>
   </div>
</fieldset>
```

this it awesome, but I'd like to generate it as custom forms in this fashion (I'm using bootswatch template):

```
<div class="form-group">
   <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
       <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1" checked="">
       <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Check this custom checkbox</label>
   </div>
</div>
```

I've found in symfony documentation that you can "generate forms as custom", but that was just based upon adding `class="checkbox-custom"` to element `<div id="form_subjects">`

So my question is: Is there a way to generate custom bootstrap checkboxes (and radio buttons) natively? Or do I have to rewrite `bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig`?

Answer (score 8):

ok, When I looked closer at the `bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig`, I found the solution:
just add `'label_attr' => ['class' => 'checkbox-custom']` to options when creating form.

Now my form looks like this, and it works correctly:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add(
        'subjects',
        ChoiceType::class,
        [
           'choices' => $this->subjectFacade->getAll(),
           'choice_label' => 'indent',
           'choice_value' => 'id',
           'expanded' => true,
           'multiple' => true,
           'label_attr' => ['class' => 'checkbox-custom'],
         ]
      )
      ->getForm();
```